# MYSQL: adding unique numeric value to table based on unique row value?

Tags: mysql

I have this table and I want to split it in three tables so i have names, a relation table between names and orders, and the third which contains just orders. so i think a simple way could be to add a unique number column here

```
+----+------+-----------------------+-------+--------------+
| id | name | address               | phone | order_number |
+----+------+-----------------------+-------+--------------+
|  1 | Joe  | Joes Address          | 1111  | 1390842      |
|  2 | Paul | Pauls Address         | 2222  | 9082309      |
|  3 | Greg | Gregs Address         | 3333  | 0928340      |
|  4 | Lucy | Lucys Address         | 4444  | 9028340      |
|  5 | Paul | Pauls Address         | 2222  | 8958399      |
|  6 | Tom  | Toms Address          | 5555  | 9084024      |
|  7 | Lucy | Lucys Another Address | 4444  | 9801983      |
|  8 | Paul | Pauls Another Address | 2222  | 0982304      |
+----+------+-----------------------+-------+--------------+
```

and i want to add a numeric column with a incremental number associated with the unique `name` value so that the expected result is

```
+----+------+-----------------------+-------+--------------+---+
| id | name | address               | phone | order_number |NID|
+----+------+-----------------------+-------+--------------+---|
|  1 | Joe  | Joes Address          | 1111  | 1390842      | 1 |
|  2 | Paul | Pauls Address         | 2222  | 9082309      | 2 |
|  3 | Greg | Gregs Address         | 3333  | 0928340      | 3 |
|  4 | Lucy | Lucys Address         | 4444  | 9028340      | 4 |
|  5 | Paul | Pauls Address         | 2222  | 8958399      | 2 |
|  6 | Tom  | Toms Address          | 5555  | 9084024      | 5 |
|  7 | Lucy | Lucys Another Address | 4444  | 9801983      | 4 |
|  8 | Paul | Pauls Another Address | 2222  | 0982304      | 2 |
+----+------+-----------------------+-------+--------------+---+
```

how can I do it??

Comment: Do you just want to display NID as query result or want to add the column in table too?

Answer (score 1):

Some what similar to your desired result set by using user defined variables

```
select `id`, `name`, `address`, `phone`, `order_number`,
@b:= case when `name` <> @a then @b + 1 else @b end NID,
@a:= `name`
from (
    select *
    from demo b,
    (select @a:=null,@b:=1) a
    order by name 
) c
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/413b73/10)

Another simple version by assuming that id column is set to auto-increment if so then you can use correlated sub query to pick the minimum id for same name records

```
select a.*,
(select min(id) from demo b where a.name = b.name) nid
from demo a
```

> Note above will not guarantee the sequence it will totally depend on id column value

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/413b73/16)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display NIDs, then @M Khalid Junaid's answer will works fine.

But if you want to add the Column `NID` in the table, then following query will get the job done:

```
alter table t
add column nid integer;

update t
set nid = (Select 
           (case when count(name)>1 then min(id)
                 else  id
            end)
           from
           (select *from t) x
           where t.name = x.name          
           );
```

Note: The `Nid` doesn't contains incremental sequence. It is based on the `id` column.

Hope it helps!